# How to Make .Net Core WebAPI Solution with Start Options With Swagger and AddSpaStaticFiles on Startup Together

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How to Configure the Program file and Startup file for SWAGGER alone with Single page application together.

Here is my Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        //// Swagger 
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });


}
```

Here is my Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
        services.AddControllers();

  
    // Client APP 
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                endpoints.MapToVueCliProxy(
                    "{*path}",
                    new SpaOptions { SourcePath = "ClientApp" },
                    "serve",
                    8081,
                    regex: "Compiled successfully");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        }).UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpa(spa => { spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; }); 
}
```

Current setup will start my solution with Swagger but I don't see SPA starting.
I am currently using VueClimiddleware in .net 6.0

I am open to any other better way to make debug environment setup and debug points from Frontend to Backend code along with Swagger.

Comment: where is the code for `CreateHostBuilder` method.

Comment: i update in program.cs , please take a look in question.

Comment: do you need two different hosting ? in my opinion you can merge both code and have only one hosting.

Comment: Okay do you have code samples for that ?

Comment: I tried to merge your code. see below ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your code to have everything together:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        
        builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
        
        //// Swagger 
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();,
        
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles(); // it should be enabled in production only
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication()
        app.UseAuthorization();
        
         
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                endpoints.MapToVueCliProxy(
                    "{*path}",
                    new SpaOptions { SourcePath = "ClientApp" },
                    "serve",
                    8081,
                    regex: "Compiled successfully");
                    
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa => { spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; });
        app.Run();
    }
}
```